# comparison current time if time across midnight

Tags: php

I've been stuck on this problem for a long time. My assignment is to set a crontab to automatically close the server "EVERYDAY" for maintenance. However, if the "end" time is cross midnight at that day, i have no idea how to verify the comparison. here are some examples:

```
// if i want to stop the server from 20:00 and to start it at 23:00, i would code like this
$current_time = date('Gi'); // for example: 1730
$start_time = 2000;
$end_time = 2300;
if ( $current_time >= $start_time && $current_time <= $end_time ){
    echo "Server is close"; // simple to compare
}
else {
    echo "Server is open"; // simple to compare
}
```

i know the is simple enough for every one, however, if the scenario is that i want to close it from 20:00 to 01:00, i'm stuck on it

```
$current_time = date('Gi'); // for example: 2130
$start_time = 2000;
$end_time = 0100;
```

how can i set the if..else comparison for the time if it cross the midnight?
Thank you for your help...

Comment: might be a better approach to use unixtime

Comment: one detail i have to mention again is that, the time is set to be every day, just the Project Manager asking me to set the server off every day from 23:00 to 02:00, if he asked me to set it from 20:00~23:59, i can handle it, however, i have no idea to handle the cross midnight issue

Comment: As you can see this spans through two days, so basically your end time should be `+1 day 02:00` or you can add your `+1 day` if end time is less than start time.

Comment: if i edit the end_time (02:00) to 2600 (2+24), there is one more problem, let's say the current_time is 0001 ( one munite after the midnight), there will be no opportunity to meet the comparison because 0001 is both less than 2300 and 2600, however in the real world, it's time to close the server

Comment: As you can see `current_time` is also in the next day, so your start is your pivot point. If current or end times are less than start - move them +1 day ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$start_time = 1200;
$end_time = 2300;

if ($end_time < $start_time) {
    $end_time_2 = strtotime(date('c',format_time($start_time)) . " +1 day");
} else {
    $end_time_2 = format_time($end_time);
}

if ( time() >= format_time($start_time) && time() <= $end_time_2 ){
    echo "Server is close";
}
else {
    echo "Server is open";
}

function format_time($time) {
    return strtotime(date('Y-m-d ').floor($time / 100).':'.($time % 100));
}
```

Comment: but the fatal problem is that the $start_time and $end_time are set to every day, the filed look like this 
[hour]:[minute], and there is no more filed to type particular date, honestly, that is for crontab to detect the 'HOUR' and 'Minute', and the crontab is run every minute